# Convert json with data from each id in different lines into one line per id with python

Tags: python, json, format

I have a json file with the following format:

```
{
"responses":[
{
"id":"123",
"cid":"01A",
"response":{nested lists and dictionaries}
},
{
"id":"456",
"cid":"54G",
"response":{nested lists and dictionaries}
}
]}
```

And so on.

And I want to convert it into a json file like this:

```
{"id":"123", "cid":"01A", "response":{nested lists and dictionaries}},
{"id":"456", "cid":"54G", "response":{nested lists and dictionaries}}
```

or

```
{responses:[
{"id":"123", "cid":"01A", "response":{nested lists and dictionaries}},
{"id":"456", "cid":"54G", "response":{nested lists and dictionaries}}
]}
```

I don't care about the surrounding format as long as I have the information for each ID in just one line.

I have to do this while reading it because things like `pd.read_json` don't read this kind of file.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the difference between the input and the (second) output - except for formating?

Comment: Just the formatting, I need to have all data for one ID in the same row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe just dump it line wise? But I guess I didn't understand your question right?

```
import json

input_lines = {"responses": ...}

with open("output.json", "w") as f:
    for line in input_lines["responses"]:
        f.write(json.dumps(line) + "\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in `json` library to print each response on a separate line. The [json.dump()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump) function has an option to indent, if you want that, but its default is to put everything on one line, like what you want.

Here's an example that works for the input you showed in your post.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import json
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1]) as json_file:
    obj = json.load(json_file)

print("{responses:[")
for response in obj['responses']:
    print(json.dumps(response))
print("]}")
```

Usage (assuming you named the program `format_json.py`):

```bash
$ chmod +x format_json.py
$ format_json.py my_json_input.json > my_json_output.json
```

Or, if you're not in a command-line environment, you can also hardcode the input and output filenames:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import json
import sys

infile = 'my_json_input.json'
outfile = 'my_json_output.json'

with open(infile) as json_file:
    obj = json.load(json_file)

print("{responses:[", file=outfile)
for response in obj['responses']:
    print(json.dumps(response), file=outfile)
print("]}", file=outfile)
```

Comment: Hi!

Sorry if my question is dumb, but where in the code am I calling my file? Because it's in the environment but not in the Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: I see, I didn't realize you were using Jupyter, I updated the post.

Comment: This code is going to come in very handy, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

```
You can able to modified your custom structure of json like below image, and how to remove the last duplicate record in json file
```

```
import json    
class MyListLength(list):
    def last_index(self):
        return len(self)-1
    
# Read in the full list of addresses
with open('full_list.json', 'r') as f:
    full_list = json.load(f)

# Read in the new list of addresses
with open('newlist.json', 'r') as s:
    new_list = json.load(s)

# Create a set of the addresses in the full list
full_set = set([x['address'] for x in full_list])


# Create a list of unique addresses in the new list
fresh_list = [x for x in new_list if x['address'] not in full_set]

fresh_list_set = set([x['address'] for x in fresh_list]) 

j = []
for f in fresh_list_set:
    j.append({ "address" : f})
     
uniqueJ = j
filename = "fresh_list"
desired_dir = filename +".json"
myObjLen=MyListLength(uniqueJ)
with open(desired_dir, "w") as f:
    for index, joining in enumerate(uniqueJ):
        if(index==0): 
            f.write("[ \n")
        k = json.dumps(joining)        
        f.write(str(k).replace('{"address":',' {  "address":').replace('}',' }') + ",\n")        
        if(index == myObjLen.last_index()):
            f.write(str(k).replace('{"address":',' {  "address":').replace('}',' }') + "\n ]")
```

[image]